# IFrame and Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage which displays an IFrame. The IFrame source page is located on the other server which needs Basic Authentication. Is there a way to programatically pass the basic authentication information to the other server page so it does not throw the login box using Asp.net ?

Answer (score -1):

As long as you don't mind exposing the password to everybody you can change URL to something like this:

`http://user:password@www.example.com`

Comment: This security flaw to pass the authentication information via URL was patached in IE6 and all later versions so will not work :(

Comment: This trick still works in Firefox 4, so it works in some places. If absolutely required, have users change browsers.. or just have them login twice